# Getting a random record with ember data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've stored a collection of records in a firebase database. 
I've connected the firebase database to my ember app using emberfire.
I 'd like to get just one random record from the collection every time I push a button.
In my controller is there a specific method that I can use for this action? Something like 'this.store.random...??"
How would you implement this action? Thanks Sandro

Answer (score 0):

Firebase does not support fetching random rows. You need to fetch all rows and filter a random row out. This should go in the route:

```
model(params) {
    return this.store.find('YOURMODEL').then((list) => {
        const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.get('length'));
        return list.objectAt(rand);
    });
},
```